# How to more accurately measure one-way network latency?

Tags: java, latency, ntp

As far as i am aware there are two ways to get an approximation off the one-way network latency:

1. The first option would be to measure the two-way latency from an network and divide it by 2. This way you would get an "rough" time estimation.
2. The second way would be to make use of the *Network Time Protocol* where both computers use synchronized clocks to measure the one-way latency.

If there are other ways then your welcome to share them. But my question here is: what would be the more appropriate way to get an estimation of the one-way latency? And what method would be more accurate?

Comment: This is going to be a very fact and circumstance specific decision. You are quite right that fundamentally those are the two methods you have. Note that the second method degenerates into the first (at least with respect to consistent aymmetric latency on the local WAN link) if you don't have a local time source.

Answer (score 0):

For using NTP to compute one-way network latency, only one computer must be running an NTP service. The other just needs to act as an NTP client that creates an NTP packet and queries time from the other which can be done using any programing language with an NTP client module (e.g. Java or Python). The network latency is the delta of relative times between the clocks of the two computers not the absolute times of one clock to the other.

If you send an NTP query packet to a remote NTP server then you can calculate the roundtrip delay based on the time from the local clock and the time from the remote server in the resulting response.

- t1 = Originating local time at the client when the request departed for the
  server
- t2 = Receive time at the server when the request arrived from
  the client
- t3 = Transmit time at the server when the response left
  for the client
- t4 = local time the NTP message is received at the client

Roundtrip delay d and clock offset c is:

```
     delay = (t4 - t1) - (t3 - t2)
     clock offset = (t2 - t1 + t3 - t4)/2
```

As defined in the [NTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc958), "the implicit assumption in the above is that the one-way delay is statistically half the roundtrip delay and that the intrinsic drift rates of both the client and server clocks are small and close to the same value".

Comment: As mentioned, NTP cannot do this, even the round trip time is an estimate.  I think it is provably impossible to know for for the exact time, since there is no "global clock".  PTP (IEEE 1588) is more accurate than NTP, but not many systems support it yet.

Comment: The stratum level in NTP is the device's distance to the reference clock, and each stratum level in NTP hierarchy adds a small time error. One way to get timing more accurate with NTP is get a GPS clock (making it stratum 0) on either computers to minimize the time difference. Can get a GPS device with USB plugin for ~$25 on amazon.

Comment: Agreed.  But there is no way to know the ratio delayUp/DelayDown.  Also, the stratum does go up at each hop, but routers allow this # to be hard configured as well.